# Regular Expression: check if a string contains any given characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a string contains any of this characters:

Á,À,Ã,É,Ê,Í,Ó,Õ,Ô,Ú,Ç

I was thinking of doing a

> "blá".contains(regexExpression)

Am I thinking right? If so, how can I do it? I don't know how will be the regular Expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). There you find a good reference on how you can achieve certain things using a regex.

Note that `matches(regex)` will only return true, if the whole string matches the regex. If you just want to know if one of the specified characters is in the String, use this:

```
String input = "blá";
input.toUpperCase().matches(".*[ÁÀÃÉÊÍÓÕÔÚÇ].*");
```

Edit: if you need to match more unicode characters, have a look at the [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) unicode reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[ÁÀÃÉÊÍÓÕÔÚÇ]");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString.toUpperCase());
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I my experience, better don't use a character, but use a **hex representation**.

for example:

```
'Á' - 0x00C1
'á' - 0x00E1
```

hex code for an any symbol you can find here [http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm). Just put letter to search field.

**Your regex will be:**

```
[\x{00c1}\x{00e1}]++
```

This will work in PHP. In Java will be \u00c1\u00e1, if sure to [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Also you can use range:

```
ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆ will be [\u00c0-\u00c6]++
```

**Latin Supplement**

If you need to find an any symbol from a [Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/index.htm) range, you can use the following re:

```
[\p{InLatin-1_Supplement}]++
```